# Separating passed values in checkbox variables form php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, parameter-passing

I found a few similar examples, but none specifically applicable to my case.

On my form page, I have multiple checkbox inputs in the following format:

```php
<input type='checkbox' name='AwayMoneyLine[]     value='$Date[$i];$VisitingRotNum[$i];$VisitingParticipantName[$i];$AwayMoneyLine[$i]'/>
```

The checkboxes loop through each XML data set for each `$i`. When submitted, I would like to display the values in a form. Here is some code I am using:

```php
 if(isset($_POST['AwayMoneyLine'])){   
     $bet_type1="Moneyline";  
     $NewDate1 = $_POST['$AwayMoneyLine[0]'];  
     $NewRotation1 = $_POST['AwayRotNum'];  
     $NewTeamParticipant1 = $_POST['AwayParticipantName'];  
     $NewBet1 = $_POST['AwayMoneyLine'];  
     $NewSpread1 = "";  
     var_dump($NewBet1);  
     echo "<tr><td>$bet_type1</td><td>$NewDate1</td><td>$NewRotation1</td><td>$NewTeamParticipant</td><td>$NewBet1</td></tr>";  
}
```

However, none of the values display. I know the values are being passed as

```php
var_dump($NewBet1);  
// gives array(1) { [0]=> string(39) "10/31/2012 20:10;703;Denver Nuggets;100" }
```

Any help breaking down these values, assigning them to variables and displaying them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $NewBet1 = $_POST['AwayMoneyLine'][0]; or if it is in loop $NewBet1 = $_POST['AwayMoneyLine'][$i];

Comment: and you miss ' after name in input =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following way,

```
if(isset($_POST['AwayMoneyLine'])) {
    foreach($_POST['AwayMoneyLine'] as $value) {
      $d = explode(';',$value);
      echo $d[0]."<br>"; //this gives date
      echo $d[1]."<br>"; // this gives rotation
      echo $d[2]."<br>"; // participant name
      echo $d[3]."<br>"; // bet
    }
}
```